# How to update an app, moved to you from another developer?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I found an outdated app on Google Play which wasn't even working properly. After that, I found the source code on Github and fixed several things. I asked the previous developer to move this app to me and they did, but I can't update this app because of the signature. Can this problem be solved by:

- waiting for the previous developer to send me the signature file

  or
- should I delete this app from the store and upload it as a new
  listing ?

Comment: i made changes to your question only to make it a bit more generic and clear, trying to keep the same intention as your original question - please review to see if it's still fine and feel free to rollback my changes should you disagree :)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a good understanding of your available options. You need the original keystore to update the existing app, if you don't have this, the only choice you have is to create a new app. You should be aware that you'd need to change the package name as this needs to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

The two options you have listed are possible and the two only ones:

- You can either ask them to give you the app's signing key (or upload key, if they have enrolled in Play Signing). Even if you reset the upload key, the downside is that if they weren't enrolled in Play Signing, they will always hold a copy of the signing key, so it all depends how much you trust that person and how important is that app to you or your business.
- You can unpublish this app, and create a new one with your own signing key. Quite easy solution but you'll lose all the existing users.